# Return a certain value from Task

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asynchronous

I have a simple XML-from-url parser, here it is:

```
static async Task<string> TestReader(string URL)
        {
            string XMLtext = "";
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Async = true;

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(URL, settings))
            {
                while(await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    switch(reader.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            XMLtext += reader.LocalName;
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Text:
                            XMLtext += reader.GetValueAsync();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return XMLtext;
            }
        }
```

I want to test it in my console app but I don't know how to return my XML text from parser. I have this code in Main function but it doesn't work as I want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task T = TestReader("http://somewebsite/YML.xml");
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(T));
        }
```

It returns something like: "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder 1+AsyncStateMachineBox1 [System.String,ParserXML.Program+d__0]".

I also tried T.Start() but compiler gives me a runtime error "Start may not be called on a promise-style task."

Is it possible at all to print XMLtext on the screen?

Comment: You probably want to `await` it. You'll need to use `async Task Main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `await` the method to get the string back. Which means making your `Main` method `async` too

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string result = await TestReader("http://somewebsite/YML.xml");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: So, to run asynchronous functions I just need to make the Main function asynchronous?

Comment: @АлександрII Pretty much, and add `await` before the call to the other async method.

Comment: You mean the string "XMLtext += reader.GetValueAsync();" right?

Comment: @АлександрII Ah yes, I missed that - yes you probably need an `await` before that bit too

Answer (score -1):

Either do what @canton7 says or if you want to invoke an async method from a non-async method:

```
var result = Task.Run(() => TestReader("http://somewebsite/YML.xml")).Result;
```

**Edit:**

Generally, you will want to use async across an entire application to avoid potential deadlocks when calling async from sync code or if possible, use synchronous code across your app. If you cannot, the code snippet above gives you the means to call into async code without a deadlock risk, that can happen if you wait directly on a task using `task.Wait()` or `task.Result`

Comment: [Stop calling `.Result`](https://montemagno.com/c-sharp-developers-stop-calling-dot-result/) or [another good resource](https://markheath.net/post/async-antipatterns)

Comment: Why not? The method returns a string so this is how to get the string into a result.

Comment: Read the 2 links above - especially focus on the second one where it talks about why not to use .Result - short answer: It's a recipe for deadlocks! Those new to async programming should learn from the start the _right_ way to approach this problem IMO.

Comment: No need for `Task.Run` here -- they're not doing CPU-bound work

Comment: I understand the links and the danger of deadlock but my understanding was that this does not occur when called from Task.Run since the thread is allocated from the thread pool. As a general note on calling async code, I still think my answer stands, it is not always possible to go async all the way up and I have never had deadlock using Task.Run, only when calling Result directly on a task.

Comment: *it is not always possible to go async all the way up* -> if not, then use the synchronous counterpart, like the XmlReader.Read Method

Comment: @PeterBons that works for this example but in the general case, you cannot always avoid calling an async method and cannot always make your entire application async so my comment still stands.

Comment: Sure, but you might want to extend your answer with things to do given the specifics of the question, then add some warnings and links to [blogs etc](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) and only then introduce your last resort ;-). Because all the context surrounding your answer can now only be found in the comments

Comment: "*it is not always possible to go async all the way up*" -- it is here though, which is what the other answer does.